# Write out a WKT file from a loaded shapefile

Tags: shapefile, java, geotools, well-known-text

We are looking to load and display a shapefile, simple polygons, then write out a WKT string of that shapefile and have the user save it somewhere.

Does anyone have some code snippets of that very function or a link to a site that covers this need?

I imagine we will be using Geotools and java to do this.

Comment: shp2psql -w shape.shp > some.sql , then extract WKT from sql script is one option

Answer (score 3):

You could use the JTS [WKTWriter](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/io/WKTWriter.html) to convert geometries read in from the Shapefile to WKT and then save the strings to a file the user chose. Reading in a Shapefile and accessing the geometries are covered in the [CRS tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/geometry/geometrycrs.html).

Comment: Yes, and invoking the method "toString" on each JTS geometry will return directly its WKT representation.