# How to convert a shapefile to WKT with GeoTools snapshot 9?

Tags: openlayers-2, java, geotools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Write out a WKT file from a loaded shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26050/write-out-a-wkt-file-from-a-loaded-shapefile)

I need to convert a shapefile to WKT to be read in OpenLayers. The shapefile is one that has been created by Geotools. Basically, I draw on the map, save it as a shapefile, and stash it in a directory. Then, I read all the files, put them out, and when clicked on they open in OL. I had GeoScript outputting the shapefiles but it causes Grails to take a dump when used with Maven (which I have to use) so I can't use Geoscript for it, anymore. All of the tutorials I found for GeoTools were version 2 which is incredibly old and virtually none of the Library calls are correct in them. Does anyone know how to do this with Snapshot 9? Or even Geotools 8? It was literally about 8 lines of code with Geoscript. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Came no where near answering my question. I cannot break up the geometries as the libraries used for that in the examples I found, no longer exist and the answer to that question with the link provides a 404 not found.

Comment: I've updated the url in that answer, http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/ will get you all the latest tutorials

Comment: I ended up getting geoscript to work and moved on.